# how to replace the result of sum by 0 if it is Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, aggregate-functions, sql-server-2017

I have 3 tables:

- Projects ( a  project can have many phases)
- Phases (a phase can have 0 or many tasks)
- Tasks (primary key: id_task, id_phase, id_project)

Every task has cost and the cost of a phase is the SUM(cost) of its tasks.

I want to update the cost of every phase in the project, I tried this query:

```
UPDATE Phases SET cost = (SELECT sum(cost) FROM Tasks WHERE Tasks.IDprojet = 'xxx' AND Tasks.RefPhase = Phases.RefPhase)
```

... but this give me some right values and others are NULL. I used `SUM(COALESCE(cost,0))` but nothing changed, maybe the query is wrong or I have to make function to test the value returned by the Select if it is null or not to be changed to 0?

Could you help me please!

Comment: What DBMS are you using? The answer to this question differs between them.

Comment: I'm using Sql server 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `COALESCE` on the *outside*:

```
UPDATE Phases
SET cost = COALESCE((
    SELECT SUM(cost)
    FROM Tasks
    WHERE Tasks.IDprojet = 'xxx' AND Tasks.RefPhase = Phases.RefPhase
), 0)
```

The `SUM` function will return NULL if all values were NULL. The sub-query will return NULL if no rows matched. This should take care of both cases.